# Redirect onClick + target="_blank"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the following scenario to happen:

- User clicks img on site (twitter icon/button)
- A new window opens up, with social share prompt (the Twitter URL used below); currently using target="_blank", of course
- Back in **other**, original window, a redirect happens to a new page on my site (freebrandingsurveys.com/instructions) so that, when user closes target="_blank" social share window that's popped up and goes back to my site, they're on the new, intended page.

Here's the code I have now:

```
<script>
    function pageRedirect() {
      window.location.href = "https://freebrandingsurveys.com/instructions/";
    }      
</script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://freebrandingsurveys.com" target="_blank" onclick="pageRedirect()">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter Share"></a>
```

The problem is that the new window with the tweet never opens up and the user, instead, just goes straight to a new page on the site (/instructions).

Thought I could create some sort of timing delay on the redirect (like [mentioned here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-redirect-to-another-web-page-using-jquery.php)), but it doesn't work. Any insights into how I can get this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You want 2 things to happen when the user clicks on an image. Try this:

```html
<script>
    function imgOnClick() {
      window.location.href = "https://freebrandingsurveys.com/instructions/"; // navigate to new page in current window
      window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://freebrandingsurveys.com', '_blank'); // open the twitter page on a new window 
    }      
</script>
<img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter Share" onclick="imgOnClick()">
```